# UWP GridView Image Stretch bug

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp, stretch

I have a GridView control bound to a collection of objects having a BitmapImage property. GridView item template's Image control has a fixed size, while actual pictures may vary in size, can be smaller or bigger than the Image. So i use Stretch=Uniform for bigger pictures, and Stretch=None for smaller. I set the Stretch property on Image_Loaded event:

```
    private void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var img = sender as Image;
        if (img.Width > (img.Source as BitmapImage).PixelWidth)
        {
            img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        }
        else
        {
            img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        }
    }
```

So the pics are fitted pretty well:

[image]

But if i clear the bound collection and fill it again, things get really messy:

[image]

I have spent pretty much time trying to resolve this issue. Image_Loaded isn't called for the second time, so i thought it's something with item caching. I have tried to set CacheMode to null, but that didn't help. Tried to handle various events but with no success either.

Please help!

Thanks

[Download my project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CADB788D49207965!24641&authkey=!AMIY5k5NcL9GLMc&ithint=file%2Czip) - i have removed anything not related to the problem, there are only 90 lines of code.

**PS** i have found the right event to subscribe, it's Image_DataContextChanges. It seems GridView items are reused, and on updates objects and particular grid items can be confused. Image_Loaded isn't called, so an object gets into a random grid item with arbitrary stretching. DataContextChanges fires each time instead so it can be used to change stretching method on the fly.

And while it works i think the Clemens' solution below is just better. Will use it next time.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this, I just made sure I was not resetting the image source to the same image again and again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adjusting the Image's `Stretch` property in code behind, you can put the Image control in a Viewbox, which in addition to `Stretch` also has a `StretchDirection` property. If you set that to `DownOnly`, the images will only be stretched to smaller sizes.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Thing">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black">
        <Viewbox Width="48" Height="48" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
            <Image Stretch="None" Source="{x:Bind Image}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code by making sure that you clean up the Stuff collection entirely when hiding the grid
`Stuff = null`

This means that in the Show_Click handler, you reinitialize the collection.

`Stuff = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();`

If you will continue to use bindings, you'll need to raise a PropertyChanged notification when you do that (recommended). If you don't want to use bindings, just re-set the ItemsSource to the new instance of Stuff (see below).

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Stuff = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
     foreach (var s in source.Except(Stuff)) Stuff.Add(s);
     gv.ItemsSource = Stuff;
 }

 private void Hide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Stuff.Clear();
     Stuff = null;
 }
```